# To remove duplicate values from table using R

Tags: r, duplicates

```
verbdata_bkp1[1:5,2:4]
                               V2                      V3             V4
1.content Document Not Received~2 Document not received~2           <NA>
2.content          Payment Ease~1                    QR~1           <NA>
3.content       Payment Receipt~2       Payment Receipt~2 Payment Ease~1
4.content             Surrender~1       Product Returns~1           <NA>
5.content                    <NA>                    <NA>           <NA>`
```

So in row 1, we have 2 "Document Not Received~2" and 2 "Payment Receipt~2" in row 3. These should appear only once in the rows.

Comment: No...in row 1 you have ONE 'Document Not Received~2' and ONE 'Document not received~2'.  The words 'not' and 'received' are uppercase in the first instance and lowercase in the second instance. Thus these strings are not duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to loop over the rows, convert the elements to either upper or lower case and check for duplicates with `duplicated` and change the duplicated value to `NA`.

```
 df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) 
                x[NA^duplicated(toupper(x))*seq_along(x)]))
 df1
  #        V1                      V2                V3             V4
  #1 1.content Document Not Received~2              <NA>           <NA>
  #2 2.content          Payment Ease~1              QR~1           <NA>
  #3 3.content       Payment Receipt~2              <NA> Payment Ease~1
  #4 4.content             Surrender~1 Product Returns~1           <NA>
  #5 5.content                    <NA>              <NA>          <NA>`
```

NOTE: I didn't use the first column values as it seems to be an identifier column.

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("1.content", "2.content", "3.content", 
 "4.content", "5.content"), V2 = c("Document Not Received~2", 
 "Payment Ease~1", "Payment Receipt~2", "Surrender~1", "<NA>"), 
V3 = c("Document not received~2", "QR~1", "Payment Receipt~2", 
"Product Returns~1", "<NA>"), V4 = c("<NA>", "<NA>", "Payment Ease~1", 
"<NA>", "<NA>`")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: @PratikBhatia  Thanks for the feedback and also for showing a reproducible example